# Python Web-scraping, category extraction

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have below code to extract quote text and author using Beautifulsoup. I am able to get that, however each quote falls under a category (e.g. KINDNESS in below html, at the end of string). Kindly let me know how to get category along with quote text and author.

```
table = soup.findAll('img')
for image in table:
  alt_table = image.attrs['alt'].split('#')
  # print(alt_table[0]) # Quote text extracted
  # print(len(alt_table))
  # To prevent index error if author is not there
  if len(alt_table)>1:
    quote = alt_table[0]
    author = alt_table[1]
    author = (alt_table[1]).replace('<Author:' , '').replace('>', '') #Format author label
    print('Quote: %s \nAuthor: %s' %(quote, author))
  else:
    quote = alt_table[0]
    print('Quote: %s' %(quote))
```

html example

```html
</div><div class="col-6 col-lg-3 text-center margin-30px-bottom sm-margin-30px-top">
<a href="/inspirational-quotes/8165-extend-yourself-in-kindness-to-other-human"><img alt="Extend yourself in kindness to other human beings wherever you can. #&lt;Author:0x00007f7746c65b78&gt;" class="margin-10px-bottom shadow" height="310" src="https://assets.passiton.com/quotes/quote_artwork/8165/medium/20201208_tuesday_quote_alternate.jpg?1607102963" width="310"/></a>
<h5 class="value_on_red"><a href="/inspirational-quotes/8165-extend-yourself-in-kindness-to-other-human">KINDNESS</a></h5>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are dealing with image tag use `find_next` to get the next tag and use .text to get the value.

```
table = soup.findAll('img')
for image in table:
  alt_table = image.attrs['alt'].split('#')
  # print(alt_table[0]) # Quote text extracted
  # print(len(alt_table))
  # To prevent index error if author is not there
  if len(alt_table)>1:
    quote = alt_table[0]
    author = alt_table[1]
    author = (alt_table[1]).replace('<Author:' , '').replace('>', '') #Format author label
    print('Quote: %s \nAuthor: %s' %(quote, author))
    print(image.find_next('h5', class_='value_on_red').find_next('a').text)
  else:
    quote = alt_table[0]
    print('Quote: %s' %(quote))
    print(image.find_next('h5', class_='value_on_red').find_next('a').text)
```